# WPF WindowChrome WindowsFormsHost: Opacity

Tags: wpf, windowsformshost, monthcalendar

since WPF has no month calendar that allows displaying multiple months I am trying to use the classic WindowsForms MonthCalendar inside a WindowsFormsHost.
Doing this in a "normal" WPF window works fine. I am trying to use a templated window with WindowChrome. The result looks like the MonthCalendar has an opacity value of 0.5 although it hasn't (left/first picture) In the VS designer it looks as expected (right/second picture)

[image: monthcalendar][image: monthcalendarInIDE]

How can I get rid of this effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="0"/>
```

If your `GlassFrameThickness` is set to -1 (or some other value that results in the inner glass border being large enough to underlay the control) the WindowsFormsHost picks up the glassy transparency.